# CakePHP - remove data from $this->request->data

Tags: cakephp

I have a edit page for my ExpenseClaim model. The edit page lists all the related Expenses belonging to that ExpenseClaim in a form so users can edit the expenses. I have a X next to each expense so they can delete it if needed. This X just removes the rows fields from the DOM using JS.

When the save button is pressed I'd like any removed rows to be deleted from the Expense table but as $this->request->data isnt changing (the changes are only in the DOM) they don't get deleted. Any edited data does change but not removed data.

I thought about using a postLink but as that creates its own form and I'm already in a form I cant.

So how can I get cake to recognise the changed data? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use ajax for delete the data from expense table on click on 'X'

Comment: Write your JS and HTML code, so that peers can help you to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this is a database entry and it cannot be deleted like this. And you cannot do it by `unset` also. The changes has to be reflected in the database.

Better you do an `ajax` request to the server with the `id` and delete the row from the database and `onSuccess` call back remove the `element` from the `dom`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Understood am now writing ajax to handle the request. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Doing these on a php array is really easy: `unset(array[$key])`.

You can | should | must - it depends on your code - use ajax to trigger these action.